# Экранизация переменных

Tags: php

Существует ли какая нибудь интересная по Вашему мнению статейка или книжка, в которой описаны все плюсы и минусы (нюансы) определенных подходов к экранированию переменных ? Или везде суть сводится только к приведению типов, экранированию строк и т.п. ?

Буду рад любой конструктивной статье, а не статье вида:

> **используйте `real_escape_string` потому что так надо**

Answer (score 0):

Экранирование -- это изменение строки таким образом, чтобы некоторые её подстроки, имеющие специальное значение в определённом контексте, были заменены на подстроки не имеющие специального значения в этом контексте.

В разных языках программирования, языках разметки и запросов и других текстовых интерфейсах пользователь вводит строки и иногда эти строки могут иметь специальное значение. Например попробуйте рассказать мне о вопросительном знаке и показать, что есть такой символ. Если вы напишете: "Егор, есть символ ?" То я вас не пойму. Вам надо как-то обозначить, что `?` это не часть вашего предложения. То же самое с языками программирования и прочими.

В мире веб-приложений чаще всего экранировать требуется кавычки, html, sql, regex-символы. В зависимости от контекста разные символы играют разное значение. В JSON-строках угловые скобочки (`<>`) совершенно безобидны, а в HTML это границы тега и потенциальная уязвимость. В HTML нет ничего плохого в тексте `drop table`, но в контексте SQL это имеет определённый смысл.

В зависимости от задачи и контекста может потребоваться экранирование разных символов и последовательностей. Для HTML -- [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php), для подстановок в запросы к базе данных -- [PDO::quote](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php), для постановок в регулярные выражения -- [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php). Некоторые библиотеки и функции умеют экранировать сами. Например, вам не надо беспокоится о кавычках, при использовании json_encode, функция экранирует их сама.

Статьи из википедии, которые будут вам полезны:

- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Экранирование_символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовый_скриптинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)
- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внедрение_SQL-кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: Ради одной БД и в угоду производительности юзать PDO ?  Я лучше ручками и по старинке - Mysqli. За остальное - спасибо, хоть это итак известно вдоль и поперек

Comment: Можно и mysqli, если работаете с mysql. PDO для общего примера. Если вам известно, то зачем вы спросили? И тогда почему считаете что приведение типа это экранирование?

Comment: А где я сказал, что приведение типа - экранирование ? Возможны вы не правильно поняли )

Comment: Наверное неправильно понял. Тогда о каких подходах вы говорите? Подход только один. Или вас интересует не экранирование как таковое, а методы защиты от SQL-инъекций? Типа экранирование против подготовленных запросов.

Comment: Да вообще все, что только можно почитать по подобным темам. Как говорится - мозг истосковался по полезным знаниям, а в гугле все одно и тоже )